# NativeAnimatedModule.getValue is not a function

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, react-native-animatable

Am using Expo SDK 42, and "react-native": "^0.66.1", while I launched my app error comes  `native animated module. start operation batch is not a function` and I got a reference from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67338245 and issue fixed. But after that when I entered the email in the login screen I got more errors. Why do these errors come and what is the permanent solution for it [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded react-native to 0.64.2 and upgraded Expo to SDK 43 and this error disappeared.

Comment: Thanks, I used  "react-native": "^0.66.1", but Expo SDK 42 support  "react-native": "^0.63.0",  So i just downgraded my ReactNative version. Now it's working fine.